# How to disable 30-second autolock after turning off car on 2008 Honda Civic EX?

Tags: honda, civic, locks, auto-lock

I had to disconnect my battery to do some maintenance a few months ago, and ever since my car has been auto-locking 30 seconds after the engine is turned off if I don't open any doors. This is incredibly annoying, as I have a habit of sitting in my car for a few minutes for a bit of quiet. Plus if I start the car up again or unlock the door without using my fob, it starts up the alarm! I have auto-lock at 9 mph and auto-unlock on park enabled, and would like to keep it that way. How can I turn this off?

I've already tried the methods laid out on this site (https://hiride.com/honda-civic-auto-locks/) and none of them address the issue I'm having. Note that this is separate from the car auto-locking 30 seconds after unlocking using the fob and not opening doors, that's fine.